# MySQL - Split a field and insert result into columns

Tags: mysql, sql, split

I'm trying to split a field (at some delimiter, in the example below using ';') and insert the results of the split into a table. What I'm trying to do is illustrated in the tables below.

Note: There will never be more than 3 values delimited by the semicolon (;) in the FIRST row, but there can be fewer than 3.

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM new;
+-------+------+------+------+
| first | a    | b    | c    |
+-------+------+------+------+
| a;b;c | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| d;e;f | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| g;h   | NULL | NULL | NULL |
| i     | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

The result of the query should look like

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM new;
+-------+------+------+------+
| first | a    | b    | c    |
+-------+------+------+------+
| a;b;c | a    | b    | c    |
| d;e;f | d    | e    | f    |
| g;h   | g    | h    | NULL |
| i     | i    | NULL | NULL |
+-------+------+------+------+
```

The query that I've been trying to use is (this particular will retrieve the first value only).

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(first, ';', 1), ';', -1) FROM new;
```

However, this approach doesn't provide any help when the number of delimited characters is fewer than 3 as it will return the first character it encounters rather than NULL or the empty string ("").

Any one have any clues how to go about this?

Cheers

Comment: Will there be maximum three fields separated by comma in the first column always?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used CASE WHEN to determine if there is 1 or more semicolon

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ae9125/18)**

```
SELECT 
  first,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(first, ';', 1) AS 'a',
  CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(';', first, 1) = 0 THEN NULL 
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(first, ';', 2), ';', -1)
  END AS 'b',
  CASE 
    WHEN LOCATE(';', first, 1) = 0 THEN NULL
    WHEN LOCATE(';', first, (LOCATE(';', first, 1) + 1)) = 0 THEN NULL
    ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(first, ';', -1)
  END AS 'c'
FROM new;
```

Answer (score 1):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed929a/19)

**MySQL 5.5.32 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE new
    (`first` varchar(12))
;

INSERT INTO new
    (`first`)
VALUES
    ('ae;b;c'),
    ('d;ee;f'),
    ('g;he'),
    ('ie')
;
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT 
  first,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(first, ';', 1) AS 'a',
  CASE WHEN first LIKE '%;%;%' THEN 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(first, ';', 2), ';', -1) 
       WHEN first LIKE '%;%' THEN 
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(first, ';', -1)
       ELSE NULL END AS 'b',
  CASE WHEN first LIKE '%;%;%' THEN
            SUBSTRING_INDEX(first, ';', -1)
       ELSE NULL END AS 'c'
FROM new
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ed929a/19/0)**:

```
|  FIRST |  A |      B |      C |
|--------|----|--------|--------|
| ae;b;c | ae |      b |      c |
| d;ee;f |  d |     ee |      f |
|   g;he |  g |     he | (null) |
|     ie | ie | (null) | (null) |
```